# Comparison of risk scores using R (Log-likelihood ratio)

Tags: r, likelihood

I have two pretty similar risk scores classifying patients into three risk groups, respectively. Is it appropriate to compare them with the log likelihood ratio method?

```
mod1 <- coxph(Surv(data$Time, data$Status==1) ~ data$Risk_1, x=T)
mod2 <- coxph(Surv(data$Time, data$Status==1) ~ data$Risk_2, x=T)

lrtest(mod1, mod2)
```

My results say, that `logLik(mod1)=-130, logLik(mod2)=-125 (p<0.001)`. Therefore, I conclude that `mod2` is more appropriate in predicting survival than `mod`1?

Comment: you can check how many predictions you get correct, and does that answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have calculated hazard ratios and need to compare those between both models (hazard ratio of risk1 vs HR of risk2). It is not an classification but rather a estimation of risk (i.e. 10% to die in the next 5 years)

Comment: What `lrtest()` function are you using? I didn't know there was an off the shelf `lrtest` for `coxph` models that worked with non-nested models

Answer (score 1):

> Is it appropriate to compare them with the log likelihood ratio
>   method?

I'd say that's overly simplistic.  You'll probably want something more rigorous, as detailed in [this](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-12-102) paper, which has been cited over 30 times. In that paper, they compare many performance metrics, such as the simple Hazard Ratio and R<sup>2</sup>, two-group hazard ratio and [brier score](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10474158?dopt=Abstract), the p-value from the log-rank test, Somers’ rank correlation D<sub>xy</sub>, ROC curve and area under the curve (AUC), randomization test, etc. etc.

Other relevant articles could be [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S105230571930477X) and probably [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15122742) well-cited paper.